# How can I get past a "Library not loaded:" issue?

Tags: c++, macos, openframeworks, kinect, openni

I started playing with the Kinect and I would like to use skeleton tracking using OpenNI.
Since my knowledge of c++ is limited, the easiest option is to use the [ofxOpenNI](https://github.com/gameoverhack/ofxOpenNI) addon for [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/).

I've downloaded the addon, and successfully compiled the example, but the application can't load a dylib:

```
[Session started at 2011-02-24 11:46:27 +0000.]
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/./../../../data/openni/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/george/Downloads/FirefoxDownloads/of_preRelease_v0062_osx_FAT/apps/examples/NI_userIsolation_4/bin/emptyExampleDebug.app/Contents/MacOS/emptyExampleDebug
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/george/Downloads/FirefoxDownloads/of_preRelease_v0062_osx_FAT/apps/examples/NI_userIsolation_4/bin/emptyExampleDebug.app/Contents/MacOS/./../../../data/openni/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib: unknown required load command 0x80000022
    /Users/george/Downloads/FirefoxDownloads/of_preRelease_v0062_osx_FAT/apps/examples/NI_userIsolation_4/bin/emptyExampleDebug.app/Contents/MacOS/./../../../data/openni/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib: unknown required load command 0x80000022
    /usr/lib/libnimCodecs.dylib: unknown required load command 0x80000022

The Debugger has exited due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP).The Debugger has exited due to signal 5 (SIGTRAP).
```

I am using XCode on osx 10.5.8 with OpenFrameworks 062.

This was a bit of background, but I imagine the dylib problem is something general.

I have the requested dylib files in my project, and the path seems ok.
Any clues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the libs, though present, aren't compatible with your system -- it finds them but can't load them.

And indeed, checking the README on the [OpenNI github page](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/tree/unstable), in the section "Release Notes", we find the following:

```
* MacOSX: Only OSX 10.6 (Snow Leopard) with an Intel based CPU is currently supported.
```

You have the source, obviously, but fixing this yourself would probably be quite a chore. Otherwise, you could wait and see if future releases add Leopard compatibility, or you could upgrade your OS.

Comment: A clear case of RTFM for me :) OS upgrade seems the easiest solution. Thanks.